# Haskell - how to handle multiline input which depends on a variable

Tags: haskell, io

I'm trying to solve a competitive programming challenge problem in Haskell.

This is my code:

```
module Main (main) where

import System.IO
import Text.Printf

getInt :: IO Int
getInt = readLn

getDouble :: IO Double
getDouble = readLn

getCoordinate :: (IO Double, IO Double, IO Double)
getCoordinate = (getDouble, getDouble, getDouble)

readCoordinates :: Int -> [(IO Double, IO Double, IO Double)] -> [(IO Double, IO Double, IO Double)]
readCoordinates 0 list = list
readCoordinates a list = readCoordinates (a - 1) list ++ [getCoordinate]

main :: IO ()
main = do
  limit <- getInt
  coordinates <- (readCoordinates limit [])
  printf "%.2f\n" (run 0.0 (head coordinates) (tail coordinates))

run :: Double -> (Double, Double, Double) -> [(Double, Double, Double)] -> Double
run curr c1 (c2:cs) = run (curr + (d c1 c2)) c2 cs
run curr c1 [] = curr


d :: (Double, Double, Double) -> (Double, Double, Double) -> Double
d (x1, y1, z1) (x2, y2, z2) = sqrt (sas x1 x2) + (sas y1 y2) + (sas z1 z2)

sas :: Double -> Double -> Double
sas a1 a2 = (a1 - a2) ** 2
```

So as you might guess I'm reading an integer, which denotes how many 3d coordinates I should read in. Then I try to read all of these and calculate the distance.

I get a lot of errors, here are the error log:

```
Akvariet.hs:22:19:
Couldn't match type `[]' with `IO'
Expected type: IO (IO Double, IO Double, IO Double)
  Actual type: [(IO Double, IO Double, IO Double)]
In the return type of a call of `readCoordinates'
In a stmt of a 'do' block:
  coordinates <- (readCoordinates limit [])
In the expression:
  do { limit <- getInt;
       coordinates <- (readCoordinates limit []);
       printf "%.2f" (run 0.0 (head coordinates) (tail coordinates)) }

Akvariet.hs:23:34:
Couldn't match expected type `[(Double, Double, Double)]'
            with actual type `(IO Double, IO Double, IO Double)'
In the first argument of `head', namely `coordinates'
In the second argument of `run', namely `(head coordinates)'
In the second argument of `printf', namely
  `(run 0.0 (head coordinates) (tail coordinates))'

Akvariet.hs:23:53:
Couldn't match expected type `[(Double, Double, Double)]'
            with actual type `(IO Double, IO Double, IO Double)'
In the first argument of `tail', namely `coordinates'
In the third argument of `run', namely `(tail coordinates)'
In the second argument of `printf', namely
  `(run 0.0 (head coordinates) (tail coordinates))'
```

I can't really wrap my head around the IO type actually, I get that it is impure and doesn't return the same thing every time but how do I use it in my program?

I don't understand how the readCoordinates method doesn't compile and why it can't cast IO Double to Double when main still is of type `IO ()`.

Cheers!

Comment: `[(IO Double, IO Double, IO Double)]` makes little sense here, you most probably want to work with `IO [(Double, Double, Double)]`. Just imagine you are using some opaque type `Point` instead of the three doubles. Which you probably should do anyway.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First, I recommend you *don't* read in a number and then cumbersomely input each coordinate seperately. It's easier to read *all* input in one go (resulting in a string), and then parse it to coordinates without bothering about how it came from IO. This looks something like

```
main = do
   allInput <- getContents
   let coordinates = parseCoords $ lines allInput
   printf ...
```

with

```
type Vect = (Double, Double, Double)

parseCoords :: [String] -> [Vect]
parseCoords (x:y:z:cs) = (read x, read y, read z) : parseCoords cs
parseCoords _ = []
```

If you prefer to manually read everything, to get precise control over the order or whatever, then you need to properly use `IO` as a monad. It's little use to combine three `getDouble`s to a *tuple of IO actions*; what you really want is a *single* IO action which yields a pure coordinate tuple.

```
getCoordinate :: IO Vect
getCoordinate = do
   x <- getDouble
   y <- getDouble
   z <- getDouble
   return (x,y,z)
```

Actually this could be written nicer with Applicative, though I suspect you find the above `do` writing easier to understand:

```
getCoordinate' = liftA3 (,,) getDouble getDouble getDouble
```

Comment: Another way to use `Applicative`: `getCoordinate = (,,,) <$> getDouble <*> getDouble <*> getDouble`.  The main reason I point this out is so that they get an idea for how to extend this to an arbitrary number of arguments.